# Libgdx show dialog

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm using libgdx for a simple pong game and I'm trying to show up a dialog when the back button is pressed.
My activity implements Screen, InputProcessor and in the keyDown method so far i wrote this:

```
 @Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.BACK )) {

        final Dialog diag = new Dialog("Pause", skin);

        TextButton Ok = new TextButton("                Ok                ", skin);
        TextButton Annulla = new TextButton("            Annulla           ", skin);



        diag.getButtonTable().add(Ok).row();
        diag.getButtonTable().add(Annulla);

        diag.show(stage);

        stage.addActor(diag);

    }


    return false;
}
```

In the render method i have:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    update(delta);
    draw(delta);

}
```

update(delta) updates the ball and the paddles.
draw(delta) draw the score in the screen.

My problem is that the dialog never shows up.

EDIT:

```
private void draw(float dt) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(R / 255.0f, G / 255.0f, B / 255.0f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();

    batch.begin();

    String text = "SCORE 1: " + score1 + " SCORE 2: " + score2;
    font.draw(batch, text, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - font.getBounds(text).width )/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - font.getBounds(text).height);

    String text2 = "Velocity: " + Math.sqrt((ball.getVelocityX() * ball.getVelocityX() )+ (ball.getVelocityY() * ball.getVelocityY() ));
    font.draw(batch, text2 , (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - font.getBounds(text2).width )/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - (font.getBounds(text2).height + font.getBounds(text).height));

    batch.end();

    drawBall(dt);
    drawPaddles(dt);

}
```

Comment: Is there a `stage.draw()` in your `draw(delta)` method?

Comment: Yup,

There's also stage.act

EDIT: posted my draw method

Comment: You should probably put the stage draw at the end of that method. please put a `stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true)` call into your `resize` method and call `resize` once in `create()` or `show()`

Comment: I have done what you said, but still nothing happens.
I added System.out.println("test"); in my keyDown method but even this seems to work.

Comment: EDIT2:
I have changed Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage) to Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this) and it works.
Dunno why tho.

TY FOR THE HELP

Comment: It works because otherwise only the stage receives the input events (like your pressed key) and not your listener that you've pasted here. You will have to use an `InputMultiplexer`.

Comment: Ok, i see your InputMultiplexer .
So i have declared it in the constructor like:        
 multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();

        multiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
        multiplexer.addProcessor(this);

And in the render method:
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);

Now the problem is that the dialog has 2 grey buttons whichi are unclickable..

Comment: This answer is much delayed.But I Hope this will help someone..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144352/libgdx-alert-dialog