# How to verify Google In app purchase in libgdx game?

Tags: android, libgdx, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I have Followed Google developers guide to implement In app purchases in my Libgdx game. 
(I have already implemented Google play game services so I do have an idea how Core code and Android specific code in LIBGdx game sync. )

But I am confused that once I bought an item by clicking on a button, how can I update the game state. For example if I buy extra life in game, how can I update In main code that

```
if (gdx.geType == ApplicationType.Android ) {
  // successfully bought a life 
  // add +1 life in my whole game model.
}
```

I have never worked with In App purchases before.
If somebody can guide me. I have checked stackoverflow other threads regarding In app purchases but I am still no where in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an interface in order to talk between your core project (libgdx) and android project.

1. Create an Interface in Core Project and name it whatever you want.
2. Then Create a class inside Android Project lets say AndroidInterfaceImplementation which implements the interface you created inside Core Project.
3. In Android MainActivity which is in Android project at onCreate method instantiate Android InterfaceImplementation before initializing Libgdx project.
4. Pass the interface inside the Game Class
5. Then in your Game class inside core project you will have access to the interface. By adding methods to the interface you can access them between both projects.

Something similar was discussed in this thread:

[libGDX Alert Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144352/libgdx-alert-dialog/29171391#29171391)

Check last answer

Comment: Thank you aloupas, I got an idea. I hope I ll do it this way :)