# Implementing android licensing into Libgdx application

Tags: android, libgdx, android-lvl

I am trying to implement licensing into my Libgdx project. I have created a new project using the licensing from the android SDK.
As libgdx creates multiple projects(core, android,ios etc.) and all of the source code is stored in the core project. I cant link the licensing project to the core project (right click -> android) as the android option is not available as core is not an android project. So i linked it to the android project but i get errors making me assume this doesn't work:

```
LicenceCheckerCallback cannot be resolved to a type
```

imports not being found etc.

Comment: http://www.scriptscoop.com/t/8a36d34148ef/setting-up-the-licensing-verification-library-on-android-studio.html the 'best answer' should work for Eclipse as well

Comment: @JohnathonHavens so can u not do the recommended method from: http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html

Comment: add setup a library for a libgdx project?

Comment: Actually I think this is more complicated than I originally assumed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700009/how-to-verify-google-in-app-purchase-in-libgdx-game might help

Comment: @JohnathonHavens surely this is not a uncommon problem?

Comment: The problem is that you need to implement something that is android dependent, libGDX is intended to be cross-platform and everything in core is meant to handle different platforms seamlessly. The android-lvl has to be implemented manually in your android project so you can access the libGDX and android main thread. https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay is a neat looking cross-platform API for in-app purchasing if that was your main intent for licensing verification.

Comment: @JohnathonHavens the problem is i wanted to just created a paid app as my app is not setup for in app purchases

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay would definitely help you then, desktop version looks lacking but iOS and android look promising.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated