# LibGDX: How to Implement Google Play Game Services?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-games

I checked [https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Games-Services-in-LibGDX][1] but that tutorial requiers me to import `BaseGameUtils` from here: [https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples][2] but it seems that the `BaseGameUtils` was removed. How can I go about with the implementation of GooglePlay Game services?

Comment: BaseGameUtils is not needed if you use the latest Play Services API.

However, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you can use this libGDX extension: https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-gamesvcs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently just implemented Google Play Games into one of my libgdx projects. Don't look at libgdx tutorials as they are outdated. You don't need a libgdx specific extension. Non deprecated modern Google Play Game services code can be found on the example projects here:

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

Download the whole repo to your computer, load into android studio, and play around with the code. Most of it can be simply copy and pasted to fit your needs. Worked really well for me.

The general approach I used was to write the code into the android portion of my project and then tie it into my core libgdx code using interfaces. Reference this post (the second answer, not first):

[libGDX Alert Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144352/libgdx-alert-dialog)

even if you aren't planning on displaying alert dialogs as shown in the above post, you can make your core libgdx project do android specific things by following this technique

Comment: as far as "linking" things so that google play games code is recognized by android studio when writing it, you may need to add:

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'

into the dependencies section of your build.grade for your android module

along with the obvious imports that can be added in with alt-enter as you're writing the code

Comment: "You don't need a libgdx specific extension." is correct, of course. If you want to do the work for training purposes, you are good to go yourself. The advantage of using a specific extension is participating in the work others already done and avoiding to make mistakes others already learned from.