# "signInSilently(): failure" when trying to sign in to GooglePlay Game Services with LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-games

I have been trying to add `Google Game Services` to my LibGDX project for the past 3 days now at first I tried the LibGDX tutorials but all of them seem to be outdated. Then I was advised to use the Google Game Services official code

[LibGDX: How to Implement Google Play Game Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121642/libgdx-how-to-implement-google-play-game-services/48122216#48122216)

I imported the sample project [TypeANumber](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/TypeANumber) and tried to add the code to my project but when I try to sign in I'm getting the `"signInSilently(): failure" error` and it crashes when I try to open the leaderboards and achievements on both the debug and signed APKS.

Here is my code:

AndroidLauncher:

```
     private void signInSilently() {
            Log.d(TAG, "signInSilently()");

            mGoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this,
                    new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "signInSilently(): success");
                                onConnected(task.getResult());
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "signInSilently(): failure", task.getException());
                                onDisconnected();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

    @Override
    public void showLeaderboards(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                onShowLeaderboardsRequested();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void showAchievements(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                onShowAchievementsRequested();
            }
        });
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.harrybanda.blaster" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.harrybanda.blaster.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In my build.gradle i added:

```
 compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.8.0"
 compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0"
```

Logcat:

```
01-07 09:56:30.011 618-618/? D/Blaster: onResume()
01-07 09:56:30.011 618-618/? D/Blaster: signInSilently()
01-07 09:56:30.512 618-618/? D/Blaster: signInSilently(): failure
                                            com.google.android.gms.common.api.b: 4: 
                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.y.a(Unknown Source)
                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ae.a(Unknown Source)
                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.af.a(Unknown Source)
                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.c(Unknown Source)
                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.a(Unknown Source)
                                                at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.g.a(Unknown Source)
                                                at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.r.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:451)
01-07 09:56:30.512 618-618/? D/Blaster: onDisconnected()
```

Comment: You print an exception when it fails. What is the exception?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Like adding the exception stack trace.

Comment: I have updated the question with the exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From 1<sup>st</sup> look of your question, It seems that you're keeping meta data outside the application tag but should be inside application tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Like this :

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.harrybanda.blaster.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                 android:value="@string/app_id" />

      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    </application>
```

> StatusCode 4 (SIGN_IN_REQUIRED) error means client attempted to
>   connect to the service but the user is not signed in.

---

Here is my `AndroidLauncher` class

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements MyServices {

    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private LeaderboardsClient mLeaderboardsClient;
    private PlayersClient mPlayersClient;

    private static final String TAG=AndroidLauncher.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private static final int RC_UNUSED = 5001;
    private static final int RC_LEADERBOARD_UI = 9004;

    private String greetingMsg="Welcome, ";
    private boolean greetingDisplayed;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      greetingDisplayed=false;
      AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
      initialize(new GdxGame(this), config);

      mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build());

   }

   @Override
   public boolean isSignedIn() {
       return GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this) != null;
   }

   private void signInSilently() {

      mGoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        greetingMsg="Welcome back, ";
                        onConnected(task.getResult());
                    } else {
                        onDisconnected();
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    private void onConnected(GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {

       mLeaderboardsClient = Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, googleSignInAccount);
       mPlayersClient = Games.getPlayersClient(this, googleSignInAccount);

        mPlayersClient.getCurrentPlayer()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Player>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Player> task) {
                    String displayName;
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        displayName = task.getResult().getDisplayName();
                    } else {
                        Exception e = task.getException();
                        handleException(e, getString(R.string.players_exception));
                        displayName = "???";
                    }

                    if(!greetingDisplayed)
                       welcomeMessage(displayName);
                }
            });
    }

    private void welcomeMessage(String name){

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, greetingMsg + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
        View view = toast.getView();
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        toast.show();
        greetingDisplayed=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void startSignInIntent() {
        startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
          Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent);

          try {
             GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
             greetingMsg="Welcome, ";
             onConnected(account);
          } catch (ApiException apiException) {
             String message = apiException.getMessage();
             if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                message = getString(R.string.signin_other_error);
             }

             onDisconnected();
           }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       signInSilently();
   }

   private void signOut() {

      if (!isSignedIn()) {
          Log.w(TAG, "signOut() called, but was not signed in!");
          return;
      }

      mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    boolean successful = task.isSuccessful();
                    Log.d(TAG, "signOut(): " + (successful ? "success" : "failed"));

                    onDisconnected();
                }
            });
   }

    private void onDisconnected() {

       mLeaderboardsClient = null;
       mPlayersClient = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void submitScore(int score){
        if(isSignedIn())
         mLeaderboardsClient.submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), score);
    }

    @Override
    public void showLeaderBoard() {
       if(isSignedIn())
          mLeaderboardsClient.getLeaderboardIntent(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_LEADERBOARD_UI);
                }
            });
   }

   private void handleException(Exception e, String details) {
       int status = 0;

      if (e instanceof ApiException) {
          ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
          status = apiException.getStatusCode();
      }

      String message = getString(R.string.status_exception_error, details, status, e);

      new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
            .show();
    }   
}
```

And `MyServices` interface

```
interface MyServices{

    void startSignInIntent();
    boolean isSignedIn();
    void showLeaderBoard();
    void submitScore(int score);
}
```

First time I call `startSignInIntent()` of interface by myself after user install app.

Comment: I've added complete `AndroidLauncher` class with an interface of core module for platform specific interfacing. Make sure your appId and package is correct and you're enabled OAuth 2.0 client ID for your game/app.

Comment: Hello, @Aryan. Thanks for sharing your code. The original question is not mine, but I got the same problem. I don't understand, how does `StatusCode 4 (SIGN_IN_REQUIRED)` make sense in this case? I mean, it basically says "you can't sign in because you're not signed in".

Comment: Also, the usual interactive sign-in works fine. Only `silentSignIn()` throws an exception.

Comment: Ok, I feel like I'm completely misunderstanding something. What's the point of calling `silentSignIn()`, if it will only be successfull if a user is already signed in?

Comment: `silentSignIn()` only give +ve result if the user has ever signed in before with the scopes that you previously set and signed in with.

Comment: Thanks and where exactly can I call "startSignInIntent()" in the core?

Comment: @HarryBanda It's your choice, either choose button so that user initiate signing process and disable/hide for further use or initiate by yourself at home screen. you can save state in shared preference by using any boolean flag.

Comment: Ok, I called  "startSignInIntent()" on the start screen, if the user installed the app for the first time. but i still get the "signInSilently(): failure"

Comment: Yes I get the exact same error, my OAuth 2.0 Client is checked and my package name is correct.

Comment: according to my code `signInSilently()` called each time when app starts through `onResume()` method, when already not signed then through exception but when first time user signed successfully, next time  `signInSilently()` don't through any exception. **OAuth 2.0 Client** is an evil with new google signing certificate (your keystore certificate + google certificate)

Comment: you need to understand three type of Client 1. signed with your keystore, 2. signed with debug keystore 3. signed with Google play app signing(your keystore certificate + google certificate)

Comment: I don't get the option to choose which account for Google Play Games, maybe that might be the problem.

Comment: `startSignInIntent()` give you option too choose your account if you've more than account, According to me there is some issue in `OAuth 2.0 Client`, go to google developer console and add SH1 key for your keystore, I think currently you've only `Google play app signing` client.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you are right the problem was my key I deleted the project from the console and started over.

Answer (score 3):

I think I got it.
This is from Google Play Games Services [official docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin):

> You can call silentSignIn() to retrieve the currently signed-in
>   player’s account, and try to sign players in without displaying a user
>   interface if they have successfully signed in to your app on a
>   different device.

...

> If the silent sign-in attempt fails, you can optionally send the sign-in intent to display a sign-in user interface, as described in Performing interactive sign-in.

...

> If the silent sign-in attempt fails, you can call getException() to obtain an ApiException with the detailed status code. A status code of CommonStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED indicates that the player needs to take explicit action to sign-in. In this case, your app should launch an interactive sign-in flow as described in the next section.

And as @Aryan noted, you get CommonStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, which means that a user is not signed in. It's intentional in this case, that `silentSignIn()` is not successful. It will only be successful, if a user is already signed in on any device.